# Left join com + equivalente no POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, oracle

No **oracle** eu consigo dar um **left join** com usando `(+)` ex:

```
select 
from tabela1 A,tabela2 B
where A.id = B.id(+);
```

No exemplo acima foi feito um LEFT JOIN pois quero retornar todos os dados da tabela A que não satisfazem a condição da JOIN .

Como faço igual no POSTGRES?

Comment: Um left joins (no padrão ansi 92) não resolve? essa versão do oracle é qual?

Comment: fiz isso @rray mas queria saber se tinha como fazer no padrão tradicional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O PostgreSQL não possui o `(+)` como operador de OUTER JOIN, que é algo fora do padrão ANSI SQL. A Oracle [implementou suporte ao padrão ANSI de OUTER JOINs na versão 9i](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/outerjoins-in-oracle), e inclusive [recomenda que não se utilize](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354) a sintaxe antiga, pois ela sofre de uma série de limitações:

- Você não pode especificar o operador (+) em um bloco de consulta que também contenha a sintaxe de join na cláusula FROM.
- O operador (+) pode aparecer somente na cláusula WHERE ou, no contexto da correlação à esquerda (ao especificar a cláusula TABLE) na cláusula FROM, e pode ser aplicado somente a uma coluna de uma tabela ou exibição.
- Se A e B forem unidos por várias condições de junção, você deverá usar o operador (+) em todas essas condições. Se você não fizer isso, o Oracle Database retornará apenas as linhas resultantes de uma junção simples, mas sem um aviso ou erro para avisá-lo de que você não possui os resultados de uma junção externa.
- O operador (+) não produz um OUTER JOIN se você especificar uma tabela na consulta externa e a outra tabela em uma consulta interna.
- Você não pode usar o operador (+) para unir externamente uma tabela a si mesma, embora as auto-associações sejam válidas. Por exemplo, a seguinte instrução não é válida:

  ```
  -- A seguinte declaração não é válida:
  SELECT employee_id, manager_id 
  FROM employees
  WHERE employees.manager_id (+) = employees.employee_id;
  ```

  No entanto, a união automática a seguir é válida:

  ```
  SELECT e1.employee_id, e1.manager_id, e2.employee_id
  FROM employees e1, employees e2
  WHERE e1.manager_id (+) = e2.employee_id
  ORDER BY e1.employee_id, e1.manager_id, e2.employee_id;
  ```
- O operador (+) pode ser aplicado apenas a uma coluna, não a uma expressão arbitrária. No entanto, uma expressão arbitrária pode conter uma ou mais colunas marcadas com o operador (+).
- Uma condição WHERE que contém o operador (+) não pode ser combinada com outra condição usando o operador lógico OR.
- Uma condição WHERE não pode usar a condição de comparação IN para comparar uma coluna marcada com o operador (+) com uma expressão.

Basicamente o PostgreSQL não implementa condições que quebrem o padrão SQL, e o Oracle só tem essa implementação porque ela é mais antiga que o padrão, que existe para oferecer várias vantagens, entre elas a portabilidade do seu código entre SGBDs diferentes =).

Answer (score -1):

No PostgreSQL, para retornar todos os dados da tabela A que não satisfazem a condição do `join` com a tabela B, o `select` pode ser feito assim:

```
select A.* 
from tabela1 A 
left join tabela2 B on A.id = B.id 
where 
B.id is null;
```

Comment: esta `query` não é equivalente a informada pelo AP, sem falar, que ele está evitando a keyword `LEFT JOIN`